# Check for taxonomy archive on search results page

Tags: taxonomy, search

I'm looking for a conditional tag to check if a taxonomy archive page(link) is displayed on my search results page.

`is_tax();` only seems to check if the current page is a taxonomy archive page and can't be used.
`has_term('','my_taxonomy')` works fine for posts using the taxonomy but obviously not the taxonomy archive.

I've searched the Codex but start to doubt if this is even possible?

Comment: Taxonomy archives aren’t returned in search results. Only posts and pages.

Comment: They can be returned with the use of Ajax Search Pro plugin which replaces the default search. But the default behaviour probably explains the lack of a conditional tag for a taxonomy archive.